# Defining an object that acts like integer infinity

Tags: c++

I've created an object that acts somewhat like infinity for long ints.  Specifically:

```
#ifndef MU_INF_H
#define MU_INF_H
#include "mu.h"
namespace mu {
  class Inf {
  public:
    bool operator> ( long int i ) { return true; }
    bool operator> ( Inf i ) { return false; }
    ... lots of other boolean operators ...
    Inf& operator+ ( long int i ) { return *this; }
    Inf& operator+ ( Inf i ) { return *this; }
    ... lots of other integer operators ...
  };   // class Inf
}      // namespace mu
#endif
```

And this all works pretty well, allowing me to run unit tests of the form:

```
  mu::Inf inf;
  long int n = -1;
  long int z = 0;
  long int p = 1;

  ASSERT((inf + inf) == inf);
  ASSERT((inf + n) == inf);
  ASSERT((inf + z) == inf);
  ASSERT((inf + p) == inf);

  ASSERT((inf > inf) == false);
  ASSERT((inf > n) == true);
  ASSERT((inf > z) == true);
  ASSERT((inf > p) == true);
```

At the risk of making it impossible to assign a checkmark, I have three questions:

- Does C++ already provide something like this, and/or is there an obvious better way than what I'm doing here?
- I want to make an instance of Inf available throughout my system.  I can't declare it a `static const` because it's not a "simple" object.  What's the right approach: global? singleton pattern?
- Is there a way to handle symmetric operators where the long int comes first, i.e. `ASSERT((1 + inf) == inf)`?  (I won't be too sad if there isn't.)

Comment: what do you mean `it's not a "simple" object`?

Comment: You might get better help on codereview.stackexchange if your code works and you'd like advice on making it better.

Comment: @BryanChen: I mean that I cannot do `static const Inf kInfinity = new Inf()` or anything similar to make it a static constant.

Comment: To make symmetric operators they should be free functions: `Inf operator+(Inf a, inf b) { return a += b;}` . Your existing `operator+` does not follow the usual semantics of `operator+` and could be confusing to work with (it does what `operator+=` normally does).

Comment: @fearless_fool `static const Inf kInfinity;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I had a typo in the original version.  I think the operator+ method behaves "normally".

Comment: as far as I know, there is a mathematical distinction between positive and negative infinity which you don't seem to have in your implementation

Comment: @fearless_fool `operator+` should return by value, not by reference.  If you call it on a temporary object then you end up with a dangling reference.

Comment: @nurettin, depends which number system you are using..:) It works well to consider +inf = -inf, and have a "number circle", especially when working with complex numbers

Comment: @MattMcNabb: You are doubly correct.  For some reason, I thought I could NOT do `static const Inf kInfinity`.  Since I can, that becomes the obvious return value for the methods that need to return 'this'.  (Make your comment into an answer so I can give it a check.)

Comment: I cannot think of a nice way to implement division by zero with this definition of infinity, but perhaps it should remain undefined as for regular long ints.

Comment: @MattMcNabb that made no sense whatsoever, but you somehow managed to look knowledgeable.

Comment: Makes sense to me. I have a degree in math. YMMV

Comment: @nurettin: Matt McNabb has it right in this case.  I'm really using this to signify an "indefinite" value rather than an "infinite" value, so -indefinite == indefinite holds true in my world.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static const Inf kInfinity;` works and will use the default constructor.

`operator+` should be a free function that returns by value:

```
Inf operator+(Inf a, Inf b) { return a += b; }
```

You indicated that you would prefer to return a reference to `kInfinity` instead of a value. This is possible (although it seems a bit unwieldy to me); a `const` reference would have to be returned of course, since `kInfinity` is `const`.

Comment: Note: initialization of a static const requires a user-provided default constructor. The system default will not cut it. I only mention it because the class posted by the OP does *not* have one. (and +1 btw).

Answer (score 6):

1. Not that I'm aware of, although it seems to me that you are using references to `Inf` and actual objects in a messy manner in your overloads.

   Normally, you take arguments by value or `const` reference and return by value for all operators besides the compound assignment ones (where you return by reference) to obtain the expected semantic. Of course, since your Inf object has no state, this all makes sense only to a certain extent.
2. I'd use a `const` global to avoid the parentheses and the potential function call involved in a singleton. Whether this is also `static` should make almost no difference (you aren't accessing `this` in any way).
3. You have to write your operator as a free function:

   ```
    inline Inf operator+(long int i, const Inf&) { return *this;}
   ```

Comment: +1. And note the OP could cover a *lot* more bases than just `long` if a SFINAE -driven set of free functions were used. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone was really helpful in guiding me to the True Way.  To help others who came looking for answers, rather than making you stitch the answer together from the whole thread, I thought I'd post what I ended up with.  Comments suggesting refinements are welcome, of course.

```
#ifndef MU_INDEFINITE_H
#define MU_INDEFINITE_H

namespace mu {

  class Indefinite {
  public:

    static const Indefinite kIndefinite;

    Indefinite() {}
    ~Indefinite() {}

  };

  inline Indefinite operator+ (long int i, Indefinite t) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }
  inline Indefinite operator+ (Indefinite t, long int i) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }
  inline Indefinite operator+ (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }

  inline Indefinite operator- (long int i, Indefinite t) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }
  inline Indefinite operator- (Indefinite t, long int i ) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }
  inline Indefinite operator- (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }

  inline Indefinite operator* (long int i, Indefinite t) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }
  inline Indefinite operator* (Indefinite t, long int i ) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }
  inline Indefinite operator* (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }

  // It's not clear what i / Indefinite should produce.  Forbid it for now.
  // inline long int operator/ (long int i, Indefinite t) { return 0; }
  inline Indefinite operator/ (Indefinite t, long int i ) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }
  inline Indefinite operator/ (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return Indefinite::kIndefinite; }

  inline bool operator> (long int i, Indefinite t) { return false; }
  inline bool operator> (Indefinite t, long int i) { return true; }
  inline bool operator> (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return false; }

  inline bool operator>= (long int i, Indefinite t) { return false; }
  inline bool operator>= (Indefinite t, long int i) { return true; }
  inline bool operator>= (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return true; }

  inline bool operator< (long int i, Indefinite t) { return true; }
  inline bool operator< (Indefinite t, long int i) { return false; }
  inline bool operator< (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return false; }

  inline bool operator<= (long int i, Indefinite t) { return true; }
  inline bool operator<= (Indefinite t, long int i) { return false; }
  inline bool operator<= (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return true; }

  inline bool operator== (long int i, Indefinite t) { return false; }
  inline bool operator== (Indefinite t, long int i) { return false; }
  inline bool operator== (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return true; }

  inline bool operator!= (long int i, Indefinite t) { return true; }
  inline bool operator!= (Indefinite t, long int i) { return true; }
  inline bool operator!= (Indefinite t1, Indefinite t2) { return false; }

}

#endif
```